# How to create an alias to functools.lru_cache for memoization?

Tags: python, decorator, memoization

To add memoization to functions in Python, the [`functools.lru_cache()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator can be used:

```python
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def my_func():
    ...
```

However, I would like to define the following alias to the above use of `functools.lru_cache()` to make the code more readable:

```python
@memoize
def my_func():
    ...
```

My question is: how to define such an alias? The following piece of code doesn't work:

```python
memoize = functools.partial(functools.lru_cache, maxsize=None)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need the `functools.partial` because it is already setup to take two calls. Just call it once:

```
memoize = functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
```

then use the alias as a decorator:

```
@memoize
def my_func():
    ...
```

Comment: Just about to give a similar response. To make the code in the question work, you'd need to _call_ `memoize`: @memoize() ...

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and the note about `@memoize()`!